# Replacement for SHDOCLC.DLL file to customize the context menu of a webbrowser

Tags: c++, windows, webbrowser-control

I'm using the code, from this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa770042%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to customize the context menu of a webbrowser.

but when i run this code

```
HRESULT CBrowserHost::ShowContextMenu(DWORD dwID,
                                     POINT *ppt,
                                     IUnknown *pcmdTarget,
                                     IDispatch *pdispObject) 
{
   #define IDR_BROWSE_CONTEXT_MENU  24641
   #define SHDVID_GETMIMECSETMENU   27
   #define SHDVID_ADDMENUEXTENSIONS 53

   HRESULT hr;
   HINSTANCE hinstSHDOCLC;
   HWND hwnd;
   HMENU hMenu;
   CComPtr<IOleCommandTarget> spCT;
   CComPtr<IOleWindow> spWnd;
   MENUITEMINFO mii = {0};
   CComVariant var, var1, var2;

   hr = pcmdTarget->QueryInterface(IID_IOleCommandTarget, (void**)&spCT);
   hr = pcmdTarget->QueryInterface(IID_IOleWindow, (void**)&spWnd);
   hr = spWnd->GetWindow(&hwnd);

   hinstSHDOCLC = LoadLibrary(TEXT("SHDOCLC.DLL")); //here the exception is raised

   if (hinstSHDOCLC == NULL)
   {
       // Error loading module -- fail as securely as possible.
       return;
   }

   hMenu = LoadMenu(hinstSHDOCLC,
                    MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_BROWSE_CONTEXT_MENU));

   hMenu = GetSubMenu(hMenu, dwID);

   // Get the language submenu.
   hr = spCT->Exec(&CGID_ShellDocView, SHDVID_GETMIMECSETMENU, 0, NULL, &var);

   mii.cbSize = sizeof(mii);
   mii.fMask  = MIIM_SUBMENU;
   mii.hSubMenu = (HMENU) var.byref;

   // Add language submenu to Encoding context item.
   SetMenuItemInfo(hMenu, IDM_LANGUAGE, FALSE, &mii);

   // Insert Shortcut Menu Extensions from registry.
   V_VT(&var1) = VT_INT_PTR;
   V_BYREF(&var1) = hMenu;

   V_VT(&var2) = VT_I4;
   V_I4(&var2) = dwID;

   hr = spCT->Exec(&CGID_ShellDocView, SHDVID_ADDMENUEXTENSIONS, 0, &var1, &var2);

   // Remove View Source.
   DeleteMenu(hMenu, IDM_VIEWSOURCE, MF_BYCOMMAND);

   // Show shortcut menu.
   int iSelection = ::TrackPopupMenu(hMenu,
                                     TPM_LEFTALIGN | TPM_RIGHTBUTTON | TPM_RETURNCMD,
                                     ppt->x,
                                     ppt->y,
                                     0,
                                     hwnd,
                                     (RECT*)NULL);

   // Send selected shortcut menu item command to shell.
   LRESULT lr = ::SendMessage(hwnd, WM_COMMAND, iSelection, NULL);

   FreeLibrary(hinstSHDOCLC);
   return S_OK;
}
```

This error is raised

`"The specified module could not be found"`

I search on my system (Windows 7 x64, IE9) and I not found the `SHDOCLC.DLL` file, the question is exist any replacement for this file in the newers versions of IE or I must use another way to load the context menu and customize it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use or rely on the Internet Explorer's internal resources anymore. As it's stated in the article you've pointed out:

> In Internet Explorer 7, the technique for overriding the context menu
>   from a DocObject host is the same as Internet Explorer 6; however, the
>   host must implement its own menu resources. The internal resources of
>   Internet Explorer should not be used as they may change or move (as
>   has been done in Internet Explorer 7).

Comment: Ok, so how I can get a pointer (hMenu) to the context menu of the webbrowser?

Comment: the host must implement its own menu.

Comment: I know that, but i need a pointer (hmenu) to add additional items to the context menu of the webbrowser.

Answer (score 1):

if the Windows version is newer than VISTA(included), try LoadLibrary("IEFRAME.DLL") instead.

And you can find more infomation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa770042%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#Add_MenuExt_Custom)